# What are these # and $ characters in css rules?

Tags: css, sass

I have bunch of CSS Code but it has # and $ at it's rule names, what are these characters for?

```
.popup-inner-video {
    #max-width:700px;
    width:70%;
    height: 70% !important;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
    position: relative;
    $padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    #padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see,

```
#max-width:700px;
$padding-bottom: 56.25%;
#padding-top: 35px;
```

What are these # and $ characters for?

Comment: Are you using SCSS or SASS ??
`$` is used to declare variables in SASS

Comment: This website is not mine. I have a project for parsing CSS Documents. I was testing over this CSS Document, and I got an error, it told me this document is wrong. So, I don't know what is this Document exactly.

Comment: can't really say with just one class code, if its nested code then its definitely SASS. check [this](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: Here is the real document, tell me what is this after inspecting this code, please. https://www.zulukds.com/css/style.css

Comment: that file is a library CSS file but someone has messed up with that by including that code at last. In my opinion, you should check if that's a relevant code otherwise remove that. and obviously the variables with `# and $` are not going to work there they are useless there, find what you need to do and change them.

Comment: So, this is a real parsing error as CSS Engine? So If should I delete these like rules that starting with # or $?

Comment: NO this is not parsing error someone might knowingly or unknowingly have included the SASS code. Yes, you should remove that it's of no use instead check for the requirement and correct the code there.

Answer (score 0):

```
# is for the referring id and $ is for the sass model CSS and it is used when we reuse the code.

for example :

# >
<div id="idrefer"> Hello</div>
#idrefer{
// do your style
}

$ >
<div id="idrefer"> Hello</div>
sass
//globle declaration
$color:yellow;

#idrefer{
color:$color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check below 2 links.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp